# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace overriding my System namespace? C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, .net-assembly, primary-interop-assembly

I am trying to fix this legacy app that was created using Visual Studio 2003, using Microsoft Office Interops version 11, .NET 2.0.  I am trying to fix it in Visual Studio Express 2010 to reference Interops version 14, .NET 4.0 -- as noted in my previous question on StackOverflow, the legacy app works fine in Windows 7 but after I close it, the Microsoft Office products are crashing when I try to use them.

However, when I fix the references in VS2010 (delete old v.11 Interops, add in new v.14 Interops) and then attempt to publish the application, I get errors like

```
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.System does not contain a definition for IO'
```

It looks like VS2010 does not see my System namespace being used when the Word namespace is referenced?  When I removed the

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

namespace and then try to publish, the errors like the above disappear and I only get the expected errors related to the missing Word reference like

```
The type or namespace name '_Document' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I already included the System.dll in the reference so I'm not sure what's going on?  Thanks for reading!

EDIT: I made "Embeded Interop Types" to be False for the Office Interops.  That may have fixed some of the errors?  HOWEVER: Visual Studio is still interpreting any System references to be "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.System" which is NOT what I want.  This error seems to be the dominant one now:

```
The type name 'Windows' does not exist in the type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.System'
```

Answer (score 6):

This issue occurs to me, only when i put the using stuff after the namespace definition like this :

```
namespace Addin
{
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
..........................
```

And the right way is :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Addin
{
....................
```

May it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue in your namespaces:

change:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

to:

```
using Document = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
```

Do the same for other objects you might be using from any other conflicting namespace.